# OCaml types/modules

Tags: types, module, ocaml

If I have two modules A and B, and define a type in module A,

```
type t1 = THIS of int | THAT of char
```

and then want to do some pattern matching or constructing objects of that type in module B, I have to use something like

```
A.THIS(3)
```

This is what it forces me to do, even after I have some statement like

```
type t2 = A.t1
```

in the signature and implementation of the module. What if I wanted to be less verbose and not use 'A.' in module B? I could make a whole new type and a function to convert one to the other, but this seems clunky. Is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Note that usual style in OCaml is to write `This` instead of `THIS`, i.e. to capitalize only the first letter of constructors.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the `open` keyword, which is similar to Java's `import`:

```
module A = struct
  type t1 = THIS of int | THAT of char
end

module B = struct
  open A
  let b = THIS 3
end
```

If you want to avoid polluting the global namespace of module `B`, it is possible to use [the `let open ... in ...` expression](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual021.html#toc77), which was introduced in OCaml 3.12:

```
module A = struct
  type t1 = THIS of int | THAT of char
end

module B = struct
  let b = let open A in THIS 3
end
```

In some special (and relatively rare) cases, you may want to or have to use the `include` keyword instead of `open`. You can find good explanation for their difference in the [Opening a module path](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual019.html#@manual.kwd170) and [Including the components of another structure](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/manual019.html#@manual.kwd171) sections of the OCaml manual.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a module expert, but you *can* do this (I just tested it):

(In b.ml):

```
type t1 = A.t1 = THIS of int | THAT of char
```

You can also `open` the A module, of course.  Often this is too drastic for my taste.  To make it less drastic, you could define the type in a third module and open it in both A and B.